# Natural alternatives for boosting creatine levels

Tags: bodybuilding, creatine

*How can I boost creatine levels without taking a supplement?*

Answer (score 1):

Aside from supplements, beef, fish, and red meat contain the highest levels of creatine; in that order. Lesser amounts can be found in milk. My googling tells me that it's roughly a pound of beef for 5 g of creatine.